# Find similar value in array, return the key

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I got an example array as such

```
$array = (685,748,810,904,998); // etc
   /index  0   1   2   3   4
```

Let's say I want to find a number `790`. As a return, I want to get the index number, in this case, it will be 1 ( because 790 is greater than 1 and lower than 2 ). I would like the final result also to have a measurement, how much % 790 is missing towards 810 ( index + 1 )

I am using PHP 7+

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: What you've tried to so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$input = 820;
$array = array(685,748,810,904,998);

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    if($input>$array[$i]){
        continue;
    }
    else{
        $result = $array[$i] - $input;
        echo "require ".$result. ' for next level';
        break;
    }
}
```

Above code will search for the value that is higher than your input in your array and give you the diff result for the next step. Then exit the loop with a break.

Output will be like this:

```
require 84 for next level
```

Comment: The result should be 
$result = $i.".".floor(($input/$array[$i])*100); rest is fine :)